# Cannot delete files on AWS EC2 via FTP, permission denied

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ftp, filezilla, litespeed

I run a WordPress site on AWS EC2 with Litespeed.

When I log in via FTP I cannot delete anything, neither plugin nor theme files. FileZilla shows a *rm /path/to/file permission denied* error:

[image: FTP rm permission denied screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

These are due to permissions issue, as you are trying to delete the files while loggged in from user that is not the owner of those files.That www-data is server user, ask your server provider to remove those files or change the owner of files.

Comment: Hi, Majid , Can you Please tell me How Can I The Owner of file, I am using filezilla  to login into FTP(CLOUD- AWS, Image- Litespeed Wordpress), user as "ubuntu", port 22

Comment: You need to use winscp and login via SFTP and run this command `sudo chown ubuntu filename.php`

Comment: I already solved it, but Thanks For Your Reply

Answer (score -1):

For this issue, you need to change the owner of the files.
This command will work for you

> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

Run this command from your ssh and try again.

Regards